# How get already installed MapBinder to add additional bindings into it

Tags: java, guice

I use `com.google.inject:guice`. In my project, I included a dependency that have a module (a class that extends `com.google.inject.AbstractModule`) that defines a `MapBinder` like that

```
public class ParentGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {    
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), TypeLiteral.get(String.class), TypeLiteral.get(SomeModuleClass.class));
        ...
    }
}
```

In my module class, I want to get that `MapBinder` and add new bindings to it. I mean I want to write something like that:

```
public class MyGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {    
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        MapBinder<String, SomeModuleClass> parentModules = MapBinder.get(binder(), TypeLiteral.get(String.class), TypeLiteral.get(SomeModuleClass.class));
        parentModules.addBinding("MyId").to(MyClass.class);
    }
}
```

How can I do that? I can not change the parent module.

I looked into `MapBinder` class, seems it does not have any methods to get already installed `MapBinder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what MapBinder is designed for—after all, if you knew everything that was going to be inside a MapBinder from within a single Module, you could just write `@Provides Map<Foo, Bar>` or `bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<Foo, Bar>>(){})` and be done with it.

From the [MapBinder top-level docs](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html):

> Contributing mapbindings from different modules is supported. For example, it is okay to have both CandyModule and ChipsModule both create their own `MapBinder<String, Snack>`, and to each contribute bindings to the snacks map. When that map is injected, it will contain entries from both modules.

Don't be discouraged by the name `newMapBinder`: As long as you have the exact same parameters to `newMapBinder` and have both of your Modules installed in the same Injector, you will wind up with one Map that contains bindings from both modules.